# Bash Logic Check - Repeating While Loop with nested "IF Then" statements

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a script to monitor my sip trunk and attempt to fix it. If it fails to fix the issue 6 times, then reboot the server. The script is called by cron via `@reboot`. I first had nested `While Loops` but that didn't work correctly so I switched to a never ending `While Loop` with two nested `If Loops` to perform the functions of the script.

I was wondering if somebody could take a quick look and see if the way I am attacking it makes sense and is logical approach.

Thank You,

Script as it stands:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd="/srv/scripts"
count=0
echo "Script Started on $(date -u) Failure.Count=$count" >> "$pwd/failures.count"

start=start
while [ $start = "start" ]; do

sleep 420

var="$(asterisk -rx "pjsip show registrations" | grep -o Registered)"

    if [ "$var" != "Registered" ]; then
        amportal restart
        count=$(( $count + 1 ))
        echo "Trunk Failure on $(date -u) Failure.Count=$count" >> "$pwd/failures.count"
    fi

    if [ "$count" -gt 5 ]; then  
        echo "Server Reboot due to Failure.Count=$count on $(date -u)" >> "$pwd/reboot.notification"  
        reboot    
    fi
done
```

Comment: it seems ok. I just couldnt understand the use of `var=init`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is some sort of violation for this SE, as there is nothing wrong with it at the moment, but I wanted feedback on the logic, I've never done nested loops really. I just used `var=init` to set the variable to anything but "Registered" off the hop, perhaps I could have not, but I'm used to setting variables early on. This is kinda a "freebie" if somebody feels confident enough in their programming knowledge to answer `The Logic is Sound`

Comment: @Simonare You should have seen the nested `While Loops` version, what a nightmare to read vs this, as soon as I thought, how about nested `If/Then` it sorta clicked that was the correct way.

Comment: your solution does not include nested if. but you can use it of course

Comment: @Simonare The `if/then` is nested in the `While Loop` is what I meant.

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a variable in the `while` loop, or to capture the `grep` output into a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd="/srv/scripts"
count=0
echo "Script Started on $(date -u) Failure.Count=$count" >> "$pwd/failures.count"

# No need for a variable here
while true; do
    # Fix indentation
    sleep 420

    # Again, no need for a variable; use grep -q
    if ! asterisk -rx "pjsip show registrations" | grep -q Registered
    then
        amportal restart
        count=$(( $count + 1 ))
        echo "Trunk Failure on $(date -u) Failure.Count=$count" >> "$pwd/failures.count"
    fi

    if [ "$count" -gt 5 ]; then  
        echo "Server Reboot due to Failure.Count=$count on $(date -u)" >> "$pwd/reboot.notification"  
        reboot    
    fi
done
```

I would perhaps also collect all the log notices in a single log file, and use a more traditional log format with a time stamp and the script's name bofore each message.

Should the counter reset to zero if you see a success? Having the server reboot because you disconnected the network cable at the wrong time seems like something you'd want to avoid.